# Wrong paths in grails.xml in generated war

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an issue when trying to deploy a .war or even when I try to run `grails run-war` it seems that the resources in grails.xml are generated incorrectly.

Normally a resource would be declared as follows:

`<resource>BootStrap</resource>`

But in my .war this looks like:

`<resource>grails-app.conf.BootStrap</resource>`

Has anyone found the same problem and if so how did you solved it?

Comment: Is it different if you run `grails prod run-war`? The `war` and `test-app` scripts are the only two that default to an environment other than development if not specified, but `run-war` runs in dev mode like most scripts.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The environment doesn't seem to affect the grails.xml in the .war, I still get this:
`<resource>grails-app.conf.BootStrap</resource>`

Comment: That surprises me.  Is this happening in some environment where the root of your project is being treated as a source directory, like maybe a misconfigured IDE project?

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff pointed out this problem was due to a folder structure where the root directory was being detected 2 levels down, like this: /project/grails-app/project/